# Oracle DB - update 10000 rows of data from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, oracle

I have an Excel table which contains around 10k rows. I need to update changes to them into Oracle database.

Currently, have written below code but it takes too much time to update 10K records. Is there any alternative way like in Java we have concept as add to batch and execute them in one shot or in iterative using `updateBatch`.

```vb
Sub ScnStepsSave()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

SetSheetProperties

Dim scnId1 As String
scnId1 = tbl.ListColumns("SCN_ID").DataBodyRange.Cells(1).value ' Assuming scnId1 is the same for all rows in the data range

' Build the SQL update query
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "UPDATE " & dbTblName & _
         " SET DATA = ?, " & _
         "DESC = ?, " & _
         "TYPE = ? " & _
         "WHERE SCN_ID = ? AND " & _
         "FUNC_NAME = ? AND " & _
         "STEP_ID = ? AND " & _
         "ITERATION = ?"

' Create a command and set its properties
Dim cmd As Object
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandText = strSQL
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("DATA_PARAM", adVarChar, adParamInput, 1000) ' Adjust the data type and size as needed
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("DESC_PARAM", adVarChar, adParamInput, 1)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("TYPE_PARAM", adVarChar, adParamInput, 1)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("SCN_ID_PARAM", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("FUNC_NAME_PARAM", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("STEP_ID_PARAM", adInteger, adParamInput)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("ITERATION_PARAM", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255)
End With

' Start a transaction for bulk update
checkConnection ("ScnStepsSave")
conn.BeginTrans

Dim dataArr As Variant
dataArr = tbl.DataBodyRange.value

' Loop through the rows in the data array and execute the update query
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To UBound(dataArr, 1)
    With cmd
        .Parameters("DATA_PARAM").value = CStr(dataArr(i, tbl.ListColumns("DATA").Index))
        .Parameters("DESC_PARAM").value = CStr(dataArr(i, tbl.ListColumns("DESC").Index))
        .Parameters("TYPE_PARAM").value = CStr(dataArr(i, tbl.ListColumns("TYPE").Index))
        .Parameters("SCN_ID_PARAM").value = CStr(dataArr(i, tbl.ListColumns("SCN_ID").Index))
        .Parameters("FUNC_NAME_PARAM").value = CStr(dataArr(i, tbl.ListColumns("FUNC_NAME").Index))
        .Parameters("STEP_ID_PARAM").value = CLng(dataArr(i, tbl.ListColumns("STEP_ID").Index))
        .Parameters("ITERATION_PARAM").value = CStr(dataArr(i, tbl.ListColumns("ITERATION").Index))
        .Execute
    End With

Next i

' Commit the transaction
conn.CommitTrans

UnprotectSheet ws
Call ScnStepsfetchScnId(scnId1)
ProtectSheet ws

MsgBox "Data Saved Successfully.", vbInformation, "Success"

ExitSub:
    
' Clean up and exit the subroutine
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    
' Handle errors if needed
    MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error"
    conn.RollbackTrans
    
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    Resume ExitSub
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have an index for the 4 fields in the where ?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? I am not getting which 4 index you are asking.

Comment: How is your database table designed? What indexes exist for it? How much data is already in it? Have you done any research to determine where your performance bottleneck is: client, network, or server? cpu, memory, disk i/o, network latency?

Comment: When then only tool you know & have is Oracle (read: that would be me), I'd load Excel file into a *temporary* table in Oracle and write a simple UPDATE statement to do that. But - as I said - that's me.

Comment: @pmdba - The table is actually generated from existing tables, and I've IDs wherever feasible. Currently, I'm working with a local DB and haven't encountered any performance issues. The only observation is that it takes a significant amount of time, and Excel sometimes enters a 'Not Responding' state. My primary concern is that if the DB is on a network, the time required may increase further. This is because I'm using the execute command for each record. In Java JDBC driver, we have methods addBatch & updateBatch for efficient bulk updates. Is there a similar way available in Excel VBA?

Comment: You already have `conn.BeginTrans` and `conn.CommitTrans` so that is a single transaction. I meant a specific index for fields SCN_ID, FUNC_NAME, STEP_ID, ITERATION if that is the only candidate key you have.

Comment: Your code is definitely a good approach. As @Littlefoot suggested you may load the entire sheet to Oracle and run a single update statement there.

Comment: ADO also has `updateBatch` - did you try that?